# Creating views on an object by sharing its __dict__ attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently looking at a maintainable, and easy-to-use way of creating "views" on python objects. Specifically, i have a very large collection of classes that share a couple common methods, and i would like to wrap instances of these classes in order to modify the behaviour of these methods.

Of course, i could create for every class a new class, following the wrapper pattern, redefining the full interface and redirecting every method to the original object, except those that i wish to override. This isn't practical, due to the shear amount of code required and the maintenance required when any class would change.

Some experimentation have shown me i could generate the wrappers with heavy use of metaclasses and introspection to "recreate" the interface in a wrapper object, but this proved fairly horrendous to use and debug, especially if A's have properties (code not included)

A second attempt showed that it can be done with fairly minimal code by sharing the `__dict__` attribute and overriding `__class__`. This leads to the following code (https://repl.it/repls/InfantileAshamedProjector):

```
##############################
# Existing code
##############################

class A1:
  def __init__(self, eggs):
    self.eggs = eggs

  # Lots of complicated functions and members

  def hello(self):
    print ("hello, you have %d eggs" % self.eggs)

  def meeting(self):
    self.hello()
    print ("goodbye")

  # Lots of complicated functions calling hello.

# Lots of A2, A3, A4 with the same pattern

##############################
# "Magic" code for view generation
##############################

class FutureView:
  pass

def create_view(obj, name):
  class View(obj.__class__):
    def hello(self):
      print ("hello %s, you have %d eggs" % (name, self.eggs))

  view = FutureView()
  view.__dict__ = obj.__dict__
  view.__class__ = View

  return view

##############################
# Sample of use
##############################

a = A1(3)
a.hello() # Prints hello, you have 3 eggs

v = create_view(a, "Bob")
v.hello() # Prints hello Bob, you have 3 eggs

a.eggs = 5
a.hello() # Prints hello, you have 5 eggs
v.hello() # Prints hello Bob, you have 5 eggs

a.meeting() # Prints hello, you have 5 eggs. Goodbye
v.meeting() # Prints hello Bob, you have 5 eggs. Goodbye
```

This makes for fairly short code, and modifying the A1, A2, etc... classes doesn't require any change to the patch, which is very nice. However, i'm obviously worried about the implications of sharing `__dict__` between multiple classes. My questions are:

- Do you see any other way to achieve my goal, either by slightly improving the above method, or by something totally different? (Note that allowing class modification / addition without requiring any change to patching machinery is a hard requirement)
- What pitfalls should i be aware when i have multiple objects sharing the same `__dict__`?
- What is the best (less bad?) way of creating an object by providing explictly the `__dict__` and the `__class__`?
- Bonus: As shown in the above example, i need to attach one extra piece of information to my wrapper. Because i cannot add it to the object `__dict__`, i'm forced to add it to the class itself, either as a class member, or as a "captured" variable. Is there any other position where i could put it? Ideally, i would like to avoid have to create a new class for every instance of name (i want to only dynamically create a new class for every original class)

**Other considered solutions:**

Proxy objects (see juanpa.arrivillaga answer) is an almost perfect solution, but it falls short when the patched function is called internally by another function. Specifically, in the code posted above, the final calls to the `meeting` function will use the original implementation instead of the patched implementation. See https://repl.it/repls/OrneryLongField for an example.

Comment: I think this is a great question, but I have a minor terminology quibble: "dict pointer" - Python *doesn't have pointers*.

Comment: Do any of your object's methods mutate its state?  If they don't, re-using `__dict__` likely won't matter, because nothing is changing.  But if they do, it could lead to surprising behavior (under various possible solutions).

Comment: Also, do you really need to use the original object and the wrapped object in an interleaved way like that?  My intuition is to say that what you want is some sort of context manager that simply modifies the method when you enter a `with` block and then puts the original version back at the end.  That would make it cumbersome to call the methods in an alternating order as you do in your example (i.e., calling a, then v, then a, then v, etc., instead of a, a, a, a, v, v, v, v), but it would segregate the modified behavior somewhat which seems a bit cleaner.

Comment: No unfortunately, i want to simultaneously use multiple objects with different 'hacked-in' settings.

Comment: My feeling is that what you are doing is a hack, but it may be the best hack for the circumstances.  If you want to be able to create an instance by providing all the state at once, then the underlying classes (`A1` and its ilk) should be modified to support that; that way you could provide all *relevant* state with an argument to `__init__`, rather than having to copy *all* state by sharing `__dict__`.  It seems to me that your solution is basically a workaround for the fact that the classes don't provide sufficient ability to copy and access relevant internal state.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you want a proxy object, which is what a view generally is. Briefly, the pattern can be as simple (for read-only proxies) as this:

```
class View:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._obj, attr)
```

The nice thing about `__getattr__` is that it is only called when an attribute is not found. If you want write access, then you'll need to be a bit more careful, and implement `__setattribute__` which is *always* called, and it becomes easy to inadvertently trigger infinite recursion.

Note, because we are using `getattr` on the object being proxied, we don't have to manage recreating the interface! Method resolution, the descriptor protocol (so `property`), inheritance, etc is all handled by the usual machinery:

```
In [1]: class View:
   ...:     def __init__(self, obj):
   ...:         self._obj = obj
   ...:     def __getattr__(self, attr):
   ...:         return getattr(self._obj, attr)
   ...:

In [2]: class UrFoo:
   ...:     def __init__(self, value):
   ...:         self.value = value
   ...:     def foo(self):
   ...:         return self.value
   ...:

In [3]: class Foo(UrFoo):
   ...:     def frognicate(self):
   ...:         return self.value * 42
   ...:     @property
   ...:     def baz(self):
   ...:         return 0
   ...:

In [4]: foo = Foo(8)

In [5]: view = View(foo)

In [6]: view.foo()
Out[6]: 8

In [7]: view.frognicate()
Out[7]: 336

In [8]: view.baz
Out[8]: 0
```

Comment: I'm currently using a variation of this, but the lack of inheritance is causing issues when the patched function is called internally by the object. I'm adding the problematic situation to the original post. Also, and even if it's not the biggest issue, it's extremely annoying when step-by-step debugging is used.

Comment: @RémiBonnet the above solution handles inheritance, descriptor protocol (so `property`) out of the box. I've added an example of usage. I can understand why step-by-step debugging could get annoying, but at this point, it's going to be a trade-off between simplicity and of implementation and that, I'm afraid.

Comment: i can live with the debugging issue, but the patched function being not used by the object own functions is a blocker. See https://repl.it/repls/OrneryLongField for the difference between the `__dict__` implementation and the proxy implementation.

Comment: @RémiBonnet You can add a method to the instance.